# How can I package an electron app with OCR features?

Tags: electron, tesseract, electron-builder, node-gyp, tesseract.js

I built an electron app and ran into a situation where I need to add some OCR features.
I figured out that people are mostly using tesseract.js but it's much slower than the native tesseract-ocr (factor or 10-20).
That's why tesseract.js is no option for me. Alternatively I could just use one of the many tesseract node [modules](https://github.com/midyan/tesseract-wrapper) [which](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-tesseract) [are out](https://github.com/zapolnoch/node-tesseract-ocr) [there](https://github.com/7eggs/node-tesseract). In theory.

Problem: Those node modules require the compiled tesseract-ocr binaries (which are usually installed with apt or brew).
I don't want my users to have to go through the extra setup hassle, I would rather like if I could just put everything into the electron installer.

Any ideas how I could get this done?
I'm using electron-builder for packaging my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I managed to get things working, with the help of a great dev mate.
Here is node-native-ocr, and it works flawlessly with electron:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-native-ocr

Answer (score 2):

You are seeking the packaging of a native module packaging with an electron app for production. The general idea is to compile the native library for electron using `electron-rebuild`. You can refer to the native module building in [electron docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules) or in [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/multi-platform-build) docs. You can set `buildDependenciesFromSource: true` to compile the native dependencies for a specific platform build while using `electron-builder`.

Here is the basic configurations you can take a look at,

```json
"build": {
    "appId": "com.trinityinfosystem.electron.exchange.stream",
    "productName": "Accurate",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2018 Trinity InfoSystem",
    "buildDependenciesFromSource": true,
    "mac": {
      "category": "public.app-category.utilities",
      "icon": "assets/icon.icns",
      "target": [
        "dmg"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "publisherName": "Trinity InfoSystem"
      "target": [
        "nsis"
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "tar.gz"
      ]
    },
    "dmg": {
      "background": "assets/background.png",
      "icon": "assets/icon.icns",
      "title": "Accurate Installer"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I still don't think that this would help to package all dependencies into electron installer. Tesseract uses a variety of additional tools, which also all need to be included.

Comment: You must be using the tesseract wrapper for node.

Comment: You mean one of the libraries mentioned above? Or a specific one?

Answer (score 2):

The node modules you linked are not native node modules (except one), but just CLI wrapper that spawn the process that is why they require the tools to be installed by the user.

To solve this issue you need a native node module, eg [node-tesseract](https://github.com/7eggs/node-tesseract) would be the one you should use. You can rebuild it for electron via `node-gyp` either by using `electron-builder` or this command (replace the marked parts with your target settings):

```
node-gyp rebuild --target=YOUR_ELECTRON_VERION --arch=YOUR_ARCH -RELEASE_OR_DEBUG --dist url=https://electronjs.org/headers --directory=./node_modules/node-tesseract`
```

Since I didn't go the extra mile testing `node-tesseract` for functionality with newer node versions there are a few things that may not work right away. In case it does not work you maybe want to invest some time in wrapping the c++ library `libtesseract` for node with via the [NAPI](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html). You only need to wrap the functions you need not everything.

Once that is done, you can follow the steps described by @Kiran Maniya

Comment: thanks for explaining! Not sure about the NAPI approach you mentioned. Isn't that something which was done by others already? I just found "Penteract", which is mentioned here: https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/AddOns.html#tesseract-wrappers

Comment: I tried to use penteract, but now I am facing following error: https://github.com/kaelzhang/penteract-ocr/issues/11

Comment: Penteract looks like the right choice, but for the issue I am not sure why this one happens, if the release build exists it should be able to load it just fine. I sometimes encountered similar issues when having NODE_ENV set to development or release. I can take a second look after xmas ;)

Answer (score 0):

How did you go about this feature in the end ? We kinda faced a similar problem recently ( we have to do 10 ocr/seconde on small areas ) so we went for " capture2text" cli ( doesnt require any install frome the end user. ) but the weight of our app jumps from 40 Mo to 120 Mo, wich is a lot. So i'd be interested to know how you solved it in the end.

Comment: Hi @Nemzytch, please check my answer below: I wrote my own module...